# I need logic for my import program from access to excel/csv

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

My program converts database Access(.aacdb ) to CSV (.csv) which gets imported to our system by WinSCP.

And It imports "the orders entered TODAY" (e.g. January 6th)

Let’s say there is an order of 400 qty -> We enter the order of 400 qty. Date: January 6th  (on database it records as it is: can’t modify)

Therefore it imports 400 as of today, January 6th (can’t distinguish shipping date)

But we ship qty 200 January 6th

And the rest (qty 200) gets shipped  February 2nd

How can I separate the orders for my query on Access to be imported correctly?

Comment: What, exactly, would you consider to be "imported correctly"?  Sounds like the current system is designed to capture orders and you are trying to enhance it to show shipment status (partial or otherwise).

Comment: imported correctly would mean : import today's shipping qty (200) instead of the full order qty that's entered today (400). Thanks for the comment! @CodeJockey

Comment: Does this program run a query against the Access db?  If so, sounds like you have to modify your query to only extract `WHERE ShipDate = TODAY()`.  I assume you can tell by looking at your db what the quantities should be.

Comment: @CodeJockey True. I use Access db that is linked to SQL. The thing is there is no ShipDate recorded.. and even if we do we wouldn't separate ShipDate either..

Comment: If there is no ShipDate, how do you know when / how many units are being shipped?  Is there some way that is being tracked?

Comment: I just found 'ordered qty' (400) 'shipped qty' (200) and 'back ordered qty' (200) fields! @CodeJockey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, you CSV is being created by a query against your MS Access table.  Now that you've found the vital `[shipped qty]` and `[back ordered qty]` fields, you should be able to alter that query accordingly.  It probably currently looks something like this:

```
SELECT Order_Num, Order_Date, Product_ID, [ordered qty]
FROM oders_table
```

And should actually be something like this:

```
SELECT Order_Qty, Order_Date, Product_ID, [shipped qty]
FROM oders_table
```

Hope this helps!